# Is there a way to use RNN (in tensorflow) to do something like a batch Kalman with the weight dynamics specified in the loss?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-networks

Or would you simply do this as a time series of models.

Basically I think you can think of time series of weights as the hidden states and the dynamics driving the weight time series as the RNN weights. I'm not sure if the data gradients are avoiding look ahead in this context though.

I am basically thinking of smoothing (data assimilation) formulation of the filtering problem. Usually smoothing has look-ahead bias but with stop_gradients (and a large graph) it should be possible to do "batch" filtering.